# SQL where clause with case statement

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, case, where-clause

I have a problem with SQL that I have not yet found a solution to, what im trying to do is a where clause for a procedure where a userID variable can contain either a valid userID or -1 to indicate all users.

However im stuck at this part of the where clause:

```
AND usertable.userid = CASE WHEN @user = -1
THEN

ELSE
  @user
END
```

I'm not sure how to process the -1 to say select all users

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps the following would work:

```
SELECT whatever
  FROM wherever
  WHERE something = somethingelse AND
        usertable.userid = CASE @user
                             WHEN -1 THEN usertable.userid
                             ELSE @user
                           END
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 5):

you can change the clause like this to return all users...

```
AND ( @user = -1 
    OR usertable.userid = @user
)
```

No need of case statement this way...

Answer (score 1):

Could you not put the whole think in an if statement...

Something like

```
if (@userId = -1)
    SELECT * FROM usertable
else
    SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE Id = @userId
```

Comment: Sadly not, there are about 6 parameters to this procedure, and 4 use the same CASE statement so an IF would end up being huge :(

Comment: Ah fair play, i did not realise

Answer (score 1):

```
usertable.userid = COALESCE(NULLIF(@user, -1), usertable.userid)
```